# Find exact solution of $(x+1) e^x = \frac 12$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, lambert-w

I simplified an equation down to this:
$$(x+1) e^x = \frac 12.$$

Then I am perplexed on how I can get an exact solution out of this. I can see graphically (split it on either side) and see where they cross which is around $-0.3$ or so.

I thought to use the identity
$$\ln(AB)=\ln(A)+\ln(B)$$
to help, but it won't do much as I will still have $x$ and $\ln(x)$ in the equation: $x+\ln(x+1)=\ln(1/2)$ Which is still not intuitive. (if I apply Lawn of differences to this it will take me right back to where I started of course!)

Any cool tricks I can apply to help find an exact solution?

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ to format your equations.

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to solve $e^x(x+1)=\frac12$ or $e^{x(x+1)}=\frac 12$. One is rather easy, the other, not so much.

Comment: @RhysHughes based on how the original poster said there was a solution around -.3 I took it to be the former.

Comment: From WolframAlpha $$W(e/2)-1\simeq -0.314923057845406053971750519462369811585944284319179466459019845$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a solution in terms of common functions. You might notice that the presence of a term $x e^x$ would mean that you'd want to use the "Lambert W function", which is defined $f(\cdot)$, the principal solution of

$$f(w) \exp(f(w))= w.$$

Then, we have

$$w_1 + e^x = 1/2, w_1 = x e^x$$

or, more usefully,

$$w_2/e=1/2, w_2 = (x+1)e^{x+1}$$

Then, the solution is

$$x = W(e/2)-1.$$

Comment: Ok thanks so it was not simple. Let me study the Lambert W function and see if I can make sense of it. @David: So no other means of deriving the solution than using Lambert?

Comment: @Steve237 No, I don't think there is. If there was such a way, then you'd basically have found a way of obtaining Lambert from simpler functions, and if there was such a way why would anyone use Lambert? Also, this is the answer Mathematica gives me :)

Comment: Gocha Thanks! So all (so far found) roads in this case seem to lead to lambert. Will accept the solution once I study and apply it to my case.

Comment: It seems to me like we are representing an unsolvable equation by defining it via another very strange W function then stating it in terms of that. Doesn't W have exact values itself? Some points are in terms of Pi or Ln or even continued fractions. Also Note W is not a function since for -1/e <= x < 0 it has 2 W(x) values for each x. I still need to know what is the exact value or even equation of this so-called function?  Very strange thing, it's still bugging me!

Comment: Well, to deal with the double-valuedness, you specify the larger of the two values there. As you note, there are some particular values of the function that are known. You're right that it's rather peculiar that we're "solving" an equation by defining a function that's a solution of an equation, but 1) we can actually solve many equations with this one definition and 2) it's hardly the only time one defines a function as the solution to an otherwise unsolvable function. For example, you can define the square root function as the solution for $f$ to $f^2 = x$

Comment: I still cannot see the lambert W function. What is the exact equation of W(x)? In other words: what is the exact solution that you provided above? To me it is just referencing a point on that graph (don't even want to call it a Function, as it's not). So where is the "exactness" coming from?

Comment: .....Is Lambert is an infinite Sum?  And does it converge...either way not sure if that is "exact value" as it is more like a lookup chart.

Comment: Lambert isn't defined as an infinite sum, but it can be expressed as an infinite sum, which is indeed convergent. I'm not sure what the distinction you're trying to draw is. If I want to know the cube root of 20, I either have to write it as the cube root of 20, look it up in a table, or apply a numerical method to obtain a (very good, fast automatic) approximation (it's even multi-valued!). How is the Lambert function different, other than its relative obscurity?

Comment: Here's what I don't have still: What is the equation for Lambert W (the graph)? Is there a site that shows its derivation? I have not seen any good ones at all. Thanks

Comment: The equation for the Lambert W function is the one I gave, namely that $W(z)$ satisfies $W(z) \exp(W(z)) = z$. Where this is multivalued we take the larger of the two real values. There is no derivation because this is a definition. Consider the analogy to the square root function: $S(z)$ is defined as the solution to $S(z)^2 = z$ that is real for $z\ge 0$. Again, there is no derivation, nor is there a way of obtaining an exact solution for most arguments.

Comment: So where do you plug e/2 into in order to get even a decimal answer out of it? Apart from using Mathematica?

Comment: @Steve237: [wiki Lambert W function#Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Software).

Comment: Go to https://www.wolframalpha.com/ and enter ProductLog[E/2] and then press enter. It will give you multiple outputs, including a decimal representation with dozens of digits. If you want more digits or a plaintext version, just click on the buttons.

Comment: Ok thanks, so the exact solutions are in terms of either Series or integrals (area under the curve) - I am wondering where I can see the derivation of the W?  P.S. on a diff note, does this site have a Latex input system or do I need to get it external and paste my equations here? I noticed it is not user-friendly to use. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure further discussion would be fruitful. I already gave you an answer regarding the derivation of the Lambert function, which you didn't acknowledge. To input Latex just put dollar signs around the stuff you want to Tex up.